# Shell script doesn't fill up file as coded

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hey guys i'm learning how to code shell scripts and tried to do a simple html page. My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# sysinfo_page - A script to produce an html file

cat <<- _EOF_
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        The title of your page
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Your page content goes here.
    </body>
</html>
_EOF_
```

And it's saved in my $HOME/bin, but doesn't quite work. Path is okay because i have other simple script working from there (Hello World). This one creates the html file but empty, and i don't know why. When i use command:

```
sysinfo_page > sysinfo_page.html
```

First it tells me i have no permission so i have to use sudo for this, and then tells me

```
sudo: sysinfo_page: command not found
```

But the `sysinfo_page.html` is created empty anyway.

Comment: ` > sysinfo_page.html` creates the file regardless of whether it is preceded by anything which produces output.

Comment: Does your script have execute permission?  Show `ls -l sysinfo_page`

Comment: It sure does now. Thanks for advice, i thought it is executable from creation since my earlier script was, i'll keep in mind to check it from now on :)